# PCRE regex matching strings that look like an annotation

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to parse custom annotations out of a document block retrieved via ReflectionClass::getDocComment.  I figured using preg_match_all with the regex `"/(@\w+)\s+([^@]+)/"` with the `PREG_SET_ORDER` flag would do what I want.  I tested it in an interactive shell and it seemed golden.

What I didn't think to test was the `@author` tag from phpdoc.  The optional email address for the author tag (obviously) has an `@` in it.  I can't use `\b` inside the character class of the regex to require the `@` be at the start of a word because it won't be interpreted as a word boundary character but a backspace.

I need some inspiration!

---

Update:

Thank you Arne, your answer gave me some ideas but I prefer a general solution to one that adapts only to the specific issue at hand.

I've come up with two possibilities so far.  The first one only works if there is a trailing space which there currently is but I'm not sure that I can guarantee there always will be.  The second one appears to work regardless but is much less ... finessful.

First regex is `"/(@\w+)\s+((?:[^@]\S*?\s+)*)/"`

Second regex is `"/(@\w+)\s+((?:[^@]\S*?(?:\s|$)+)*)/"`

Perhaps someone can help me clean up the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\b as word boundary can't be used inside a character class, because \b as word boundary is a pattern, not a character.

I guess you want to match something like

```
@import file @author firstname lastname <mail@address.com>
```

and your interested in the annotations name and parameter.

If you simply extend your character family to not contain the `<` and append an optional pattern for the mail address, you may end up with something like this:

```
(@\w+)\s+([^<@]+(?:<[^>]+>)?)
```

I don't know if this matches all annotations of your interest, but may be it's a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the 'why' the `\b` doesn't work inside a character class.  Also in deciphering your suggestion I learned about suppressing a capture which I had not come across before which is awesome =)